# How can I create a DSL similar to Pester in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

The Vester project creates pester tests that follow a specific pattern of Describe, It, Try, Catch, Remdiate to test and then fix issues with a VMWare environment, Ex. [Update-DNS.Tests.ps1](https://github.com/WahlNetwork/Vester/blob/master/Tests/Update-DNS.Tests.ps1).

In semi-pseudo code, the core of the algorithm is the following:

```
Param(
    [switch]$Remediate = $false
)

Process {
    Describe -Name "Test Group Name" -Tag @("Tag") -Fixture {
        #Some code to load up state for the test group
        foreach ($Thing in $Things) {
            It -name "Name of first test" -test {
                #Some code to load up state for the test
                try {
                    #Conditional tests using Pester syntax
                } catch {
                    if ($Remediate) {
                        Write-Warning -Message $_
                        Write-Warning -Message "Remediation Message"
                        #Code to remediate issues
                    } else {
                        throw $_
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to write the code that would allow for the following Pester like DSL syntax:

```
Param(
    [switch]$Remediate = $false
)
CheckGroup "AD User Checks" {
    ForEach($Aduser in (Get-aduser -Filter * -Properties HomeDirectory)) {
        Check "Home directory path exists" {
            Condition {
                if ($Aduser.HomeDirectory) {
                    Test-path $Aduser.HomeDirectory | Should be $true
                }
            }
            Remdiation "Create home directory that doesn't exist" {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Aduser.HomeDirectory
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this would result in something like the following actually being run:

```
Describe -Name "AD User Checks" -Fixture {
    ForEach($Aduser in (Get-aduser -Filter * -Properties HomeDirectory)) {
        It -name "Home directory path exists" -test {
            try {
                if ($Aduser.HomeDirectory) {
                    Test-path $Aduser.HomeDirectory | Should be $true
                }
            } catch {
                if ($Remediate) {
                    Write-Warning -Message $_
                    Write-Warning -Message "Create home directory that doesn't exist"
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Aduser.HomeDirectory
                } else {
                    throw $_
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I go about implementing this DSL designed specifically for performing checks and remediations?

Here is some of the code that I have written to try to accomplish this:

```
Function CheckGroup {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)][String]$Name,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]$CheckGroupScriptBlock
    )
    Describe $CheckGroupName -Fixture $CheckGroupScriptBlock
}


Function Check {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)][String]$Name,
        $ConditionScriptBlock,
        $RemediationScriptBlock
    )
    It -name $Name -test {
        try {
            & $ConditionScriptBlock
        } catch {
            & $RemediationScriptBlock
        }
    }
}

Function Condition {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]$ScriptBlock
    )
    & $ScriptBlock
}

Function Remediation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $Name,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]$ScriptBlock,
        [bool]$Remediate = $false
    )
    if ($Remediate) {
        Write-Verbose $_
        Write-Verbose $Name
        & $ScriptBlock
    } else {
        throw $_
    }
}
```

For the function `Check` I really need to be able to take in a single script block as a parameter but somehow find the `Condition` and `Remediation` function calls inside the script block passed and split them out of the script block and blend them into the appropriate spot in the `Try {} Catch {}` inside the `It` in the `Check` function.

Comment: The example you post is not a subset (nor a superset) of Pester - it's just another DSL - what's the real question here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, I have changed the question to remove any reference to subset, I am asking how can I implement this DSL in PowerShell. I have the PowerShell code that works listed that uses Pester but I want the code to be more DRY and the ways that I have tried to implement the DSL have all had problems.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what problems did you encounter? An obvious approach would be to define `CheckGroup` as an alias for `Describe`, then define `Check` as a function accepting a string and a scriptblock. Modify the scriptblock AST and invoke `It`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen "Modify the scriptblock AST" That was the part I got stuck on, I don't know how to work with the script block AST though I saw it was a property of the script block object. I would really like to learn this though. I will try to post the code I have tried as soon as I can, it felt like it would make this question too long but that was probably the wrong decision. Thanks